# How to remove after, before view controllers in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to remove all cached before & after view controllers in `UIPageViewController` so that new before and after view controllers are made when users scroll the `UIPageViewController`.

How can I remove the cached before and after view controllers?

I need many functions that can control `UIPageViewController` but it seems like there are few functions to do that.

*I attached simplified version of my code.
The overall call sequence is quite complicated since it includes Alamofire HTTP requests and work asynchronously.

```
class ViewCalendarPageVC: UIPageViewController {

    var targetViewCalendarVC: ViewCalendarVC2?
    var viewCalendarVC: ViewCalendarVC2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        viewCalendarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewCalendarVC2") as! ViewCalendarVC2

        var parentVC: TopViewController = (self.parent as? TopViewController)!
        viewCalendarVC!.selectedMonthYear = parentVC.selectedMonthYear!

        setViewControllers([viewCalendarVC!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showCalendar(){
        targetViewCalendarVC?.showCalendar()        
    }

}
extension ViewCalendarPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {                
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewCalendarVC2") as! ViewCalendarVC2

        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.month = -1//monthsToAdd
        dateComponent.day = 0 //daysToAdd
        dateComponent.year = 0 //yearsToAdd

        var parentVC: TopViewController = (self.parent as? TopViewController)!

        viewController.selectedMonthYear = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: parentVC.selectedMonthYear!)

        return viewController
   }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {             
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewCalendarVC2") as! ViewCalendarVC2

        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.month = +1//monthsToAdd
        dateComponent.day = 0 //daysToAdd
        dateComponent.year = 0 //yearsToAdd

        var parentVC: TopViewController = (self.parent as? TopViewController)!

        viewController.selectedMonthYear = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: parentVC.selectedMonthYear!)

        return viewController
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by cached viewControllers? UIPageViewController doesn't do any caching things.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan Hi. What I mean is view controllers that is created when users scroll UIPageViewController.

Comment: Can you share the data source delegate you have used with your pageviewcontroller?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan Of course. I attached my code.

Comment: Here, you are always initializing and returning a new viewController from your data source. There is no sort of caching it. That what do you exactly want to clear?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan I added debug log to know when the data source functions are called. The functions are called when users scroll the page slightly first. And when users scroll the page slightly again then.. the data source functions are not called. So I thought the before & after view controllers are created and cached. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to 'reset' cache is `setViewControllers` method from the `UIPageViewController`:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

So to do this after a user scroll, the displayed ViewController should notify the PageViewController just after it appears:

```
protocol MyPageViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func viewControllerDidAppear(_ vc: UIViewController)
}

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, MyPageViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vc = MyViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func viewControllerDidAppear(_ vc: UIViewController) {
        setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: MyPageViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        delegate?.viewControllerDidAppear(self)
    }
}
```

**Note: I didn't test this code, maybe it can lead to an infinite loop if `viewDidAppear` is called every time after `setViewControllers` is called. Give a try and let me know**

---

UPDATE:

```
protocol MyPageViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func viewControllerDidAppear(_ vc: UIViewController)
}

class ViewCalendarPageVC: UIPageViewController {

    var targetViewCalendarVC: ViewCalendarVC2?
    var viewCalendarVC: ViewCalendarVC2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        viewCalendarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewCalendarVC2") as! ViewCalendarVC2

        var parentVC: TopViewController = (self.parent as? TopViewController)!
        viewCalendarVC!.selectedMonthYear = parentVC.selectedMonthYear!
        viewCalendarVC.delegate = self // ADD THIS and implement ViewCalendarVC2 as MyViewController above

        setViewControllers([viewCalendarVC!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showCalendar(){
        targetViewCalendarVC?.showCalendar()
    }

    //MyPageViewControllerDelegate
    func viewControllerDidAppear(_ vc: UIViewController) {
        setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Um.. It's hard to apply your code because my code call sequence is complex.. I'm sorry. Alternatively Is there a way to access the before and after view controllers? I used pageViewController(<#T##pageViewController: UIPageViewController##UIPageViewController#>, viewControllerAfter: <#T##UIViewController#>) function but.. it didn't work.

Comment: You just need to insert it in your code: MyPageViewController is equivalent to ViewCalendarPageVC and MyViewController is equivalent to ViewCalendarVC2

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to implement it in your code

Comment: I had understood what you mean but my code structure is.. quite complex.. I couldn't apply it. To apply it I have to change a few of my code and it is risky. Is there a way  to access the before and after view controllers?